# How to initialize a View by observing @StateObject from other View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, observedobject, property-observer

I have 2 Views inside a `TabView` (each view is in a different view file):

1. For adding employees (AddEmployeeView.swift)
2. For displaying employees (AllEmployeesView.swift)

and I also have a View Model in EmployeeDB.swift .
I want to use the same object ( `@StateObject var viewModel = EmployeeViewModel()` ) from AddEmployeeView.swift to access and display viewModel 's info in AllEmployeesView.swift. I tried
using `@ObservedObject` to do so which is working, but when I initialize this view (`AllEmployeesView()`)in `TabView` this error ( *Missing argument for parameter 'viewModel' in call* ) pops up.
How can I access the updated data like `AddEmployeeView` 's `viewModel.allEmployees`  from the `AllEmployeesView` View?

**ContentView.swift**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView() {
            AddEmployeeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Add")
                }
            
            AllEmployeesView() //Missing argument for parameter 'viewModel' in call
                .tabItem {
                    Text("All Employee")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**EmployeeDB.swift**

```
class EmployeeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var allEmployees = [Employee]()
    @Published var name : String = ""
    @Published var id : String = ""
    
    struct Employee: Identifiable {
        let name : String
        let id: String
    }
    
    func save() {
        let newEmployee = Employee(name: name, id: id)
        allEmployees.append(newEmployee)
    }
    
    func getEmployees() -> [Employee] {
        return allEmployees
    }
    
}
```

**AddEmployeeView.swift**

```
struct AddEmployeeView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = EmployeeViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Name", text: $viewModel.name)
            TextField("Id", text: $viewModel.id)
            Button ("Save") {
                viewModel.save()
            }
        }
        .background(.gray)
        .padding()
    }
}

struct AddEmployeeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddEmployeeView()
    }
}
```

**AllEmployeesView.swift**

```
struct AllEmployeesView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: EmployeeViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
    
        List {
            let allEmployees = viewModel.allEmployees
            ForEach(allEmployees) { employee in
                Text(employee.name)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AllEmployeesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AllEmployeesView(viewModel: EmployeeViewModel())
    }
}
```

Comment: Create your viewModel as a `@StateObject` in `ContentView` and pass it to `AddEmployeeView(viewModel: viewModel)` and `AllEmployeesView(viewModel: viewModel)` where it is declared as `@ObservedObject`.

Comment: thank you so much, it solved my problem, just wondering if I put `EmployeeViewModel: ObservableObject` class into `AddEmployeeView `'s Extenstion then how can I achieve the same thing.

Comment: Replace the `@StateObject` line in `AddEmployeeView` with `@ObservedObject var viewModel: EmployeeViewModel` and then pass in `viewModel` from the callers.

Comment: Can you please put it as an answer? so that I can mark it solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have one source of truth for your `viewModel`.
Create your `viewModel` as a `@StateObject` in `ContentView` and pass it to `AddEmployeeView` and `AllEmployeesView`.

In order to do that, declare:

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel: EmployeeViewModel
```

in both `AddEmployeeView` and `AllEmployeesView`. Then pass in `viewModel` from `ContentView` like this:

```
AddEmployeeView(viewModel: viewModel)
```

and

```
AllEmployeesView(viewModel: viewModel)
```

That way, all three of your views will be working from the same `viewModel` which keeps everything in sync.